# Watin C# classes are getting very big, whats the best way to break them out

Tags: c#, watin

In testing a site, I end up getting really long class files testing lots of different parts of a website.  I could break them into separate classes but then I would need to pass around Browser Objects and seems like lots of extra overhead. I could also add a "code file" which I think could just be included in the main class I'm working in and have it hold functions. Whats the right way to break up a big c# class file into smaller files?

Comment: You need to partition them logically based on their domains. In other note: i would recommend code generators.

Comment: You are deriving from the Page class and putting your page logic in those classes, right?  If not, look into that as it is a HUGE help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said your class "testing lots of different parts of a website" make a single class for single part of a website.
For instance you can take two steps for refactoring.
1. Break class into several files using partial keyword.
2. Step by step remove partial and rename class name accroding to its responsobility.

Answer (score 3):

I would break them into files grouped by similar functionality, and use the [partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword.

Also -

If your class is getting that big, I suspect that you are loading it up with too many responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Whats the right way to break up a big c# class file into smaller files?
```

Its to seperate it into seperate classes.

A class should have a single purpose, a method should do a single action, good code should explain itself.

Answer (score 0):

We have over 250 tests in our project.  We initially used partial classes but found finding a specific test to run a pain, so we've structured the classes like this: -

```
- class Base
  - class Site1
    - class LoginTests
      - ValidLogin()
      - InvalidLogin()
    + class MyAccountTests
    + class MiscTests
  - class Site2
    + class LoginTests
    + class MyAccountTests
    + class MiscTests
  - class Site3
    + class LoginTests
    + class MyAccountTests
    + class MiscTests
```

Then, in your Test View window in VS group them by Test Name which will show you...

```
- Site1.LoginTests
  - ValidLogin
  - InvalidLogin
+ Site1.MyAccountTests
+ Site1.MiscTests
+ Site2.LoginTests
+ Site2.MyAccountTests
+ Site2.MiscTests
+ Site3.LoginTests
+ Site3.MyAccountTests
+ Site3.MiscTests
```